# PHP - How can I retrieve access to these APIS?

Tags: php, curl, cookies, authentication, manual

I have tried to use cURL in PHP to login to the site https://play.binweevils.com But I have failed to do so. This is the HTML FORM code of the login page :

```
<!--Login Form -->
        <form id="login-play-form" action="https://www.binweevils.com/login" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_url" value="https://play.binweevils.com/game.php">
        <input class="name login-payment-input" type="text" name="userID" id="userID" value="" required>
        <input class="password login-payment-input" type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
        <a class="remember-me" onclick="toggleTick(); return false;">
                <label for="rememberMe">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" id="rememberMe" checked="checked">
                    <input type="hidden" name="form_token" id="form_token" value="aea58a7b633f2d75c0a6235a5ce65797" />
```

And below is my attempted PHP :

```
function login(){

$ch = curl_init("https://www.binweevils.com/login");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'userID=mo_salah&password=test&rememberMe=on&form_token=0c2fde897a3c212f5b7b759b45e023b2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36 OPR/47.0.2631.55');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

For some reason this isn't working. I would appreciate if anyone can help to make any amendments. This is the data being posted to the URL : 
[Data being parsed to URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZelL.png) (PLEASE NOTE THE FORM TOKEN IS NOT THE SAME, IT DIFFERENTIATES EVERY TIME)

**EDIT : THE LOGIN FUNCTION WORKS**

However when attempting to access an API in the game via CURL, an error occurs.

```
function changeDef(login) {         
    $curl = curl_init("http://lb.binweevils.com/weevil/change-definition?rndVar=");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);
    $timer = 201186;
    $idx = 223743722;
    $weevilDef = 422430521103011300; 
    $hash = "51f4aaecdd00ca5aa00cc7a48e2917d3";
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "hash=".$hash."&weevilDef=".$weevilDef."&st=".$timer."&idx=".$idx);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    $responsedef = trim(curl_exec($curl));
    curl_close($curl);
    print $responsedef;
}
```

The error is the following  : [image: Error] How can I fix this?

Comment: Whenever your are troubleshooting without sufficient info to go on, instead of randomly trying things to make it work, try finding out how to get more info.  In this case, after `curl_exec($ch);` do this: `echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);`

Comment: Cheers, it stated there was no error.

Comment: So, if there was no error but it "isn't working", can you be more specific?  What is the expected result and what result did you get?  We need more info in order to help.

Comment: please see edit @BareNakedCoder

Answer (score 0):

So, the web app is rejecting your request because a value for "userIDX" is not in its session data.  Without knowing the web app's code, it's tough to know the reason why other than to guess.  You do send `idx=...` so I'm guessing that's where it would get the value of "userIDX".

Guess #1 (fingers crossed):  The [PHP doc for curl_setopt()[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says there are two ways to set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS: string or array.  It then says "If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data".  This implies that if value is string, this header is not set.  And (guessing here) that might be why it doesn't get idx.  So, try this (while crossing fingers):

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [ 
    "hash" => $hash, 
    "weevilDef" => $weevilDef,
    "st" => $timer,
    "idx" => $idx
]);
```